# hincrby and hget returning True instead of actual value in Redis (python)

Tags: python, redis, pipeline

For performance improvements, I have used the Redis pipeline instead of single insertions. Please find the code snippet for the same.

```
r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=redis_pool)
r_pipeline = r.pipeline()
for key in keys:
    r_pipeline.hincrby(key, hash, amount)
    r_pipeline.expire(key, Globals.Cache.ttl)
return r_pipeline.execute()
```

the return value of r_pipeline.execute() is a list. Based on the documentation it supposes to increment and return the incremented value. But sometimes it is actually returning the value and sometimes it is just returning **True**.

I have gone through the documentation and did google but still not able to figure out why hincrby is returning True in the pipeline.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `True` is coming from the expire call in the pipeline. In isolation:

```py
>>> p.hincrby('key', 'val', 1)
Pipeline<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
>>> p.expire('key', 120)
Pipeline<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
>>> print(p.execute())
[1L, True]
```